# Pseudo element affecting outline

Tags: html, css

Pretty sure this is a bug with Firefox, but perhaps someone can weigh in.

I am applying an outline around a 100x100 box.  When you use a pseudo element that is positioned absolute it should remove it from document flow, but it appears it still is affecting the flow of the outline property.  IE and Chrome appear to render this as I would expect, where the black outline stays positioned to the main element. Any ideas?

[image]

```css
.content
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  outline:1px solid black;
  border:1px solid yellow;
  position:relative;
}

.content:after
{
  position:absolute;
  content:'pseudo';
  background-color:salmon;
  width:200px;
  top:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/gatupogiwi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Updated with image for IE, Firefox, Chrome

Comment: I'd say that was a bug...and not a new one.

Comment: some say its a bug: [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697899) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687311), others say not so really, its been this way for some time now I think

Comment: Why not just remove `position: relative` http://jsfiddle.net/k7z7sqay/26/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I require the pseudo element to be positioned based off the location of the node.  Positioning against the document unfortunately wont work.

Comment: @cgatian now I am above my pay grade with this but would it work if you removed relative and put it here instead? `.content:before{ position: relative;}`

Comment: I see this happening for Chrome too; interestingly not for a link element (`<a>`), but for a `<button>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `outline` style to `box-shadow`:

```
outline:1px solid black;
```

to:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I did some quick tests and it works. Let me do some more testing and I'll accept

Comment: Just be aware that `outline-style: auto` (the default) makes outlines behave differently from `outline-style: solid` and you cannot mimic _that_ behavior with only a `box-shadow`.
The difference is that when you mouse-click a link (`<a>`) element, it _will_ receive focus, however an `a:focus{ outline: ... auto ...; }` will _not_ be rendered in that case.